# Finding all the polynomials such that $p(1)=2, p(2)=3$

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing

So the full problem is:
Find all the polynomials $p$ of degree at most $2016$ such that $p(1) = 2, p(2) = 3,..., p(2017) = 2018$.

It seems that the degree value of 2016 is arbitrary but beyond that I'm not sure where to start, any ideas?

Comment: Think about $p(x)-x-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution is given by

$$f(x)=x+1+P(x)(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-2017),$$

where $P(x)$ is a general polynomial. Since $f(x)$ is known to be a polynomial with degree no more than $2016$, we have $P(x)=0$. This is because $(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-2017)$ has degree $2017$. If $P(x)\neq 0$, we have $\deg P\geq 0$. Therefore, the degree of the extra term is $\geq 2017$, contradicting our premise. Therefore $P(x)=0$ ($\deg P=-\infty$), which means $f(x)=x+1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Im a bit confused about how P(x) will equal 0. Also what theorem is used to know (x-1)(x-2)...(x-2017) has a degree of 2017.(my prof went over this section pretty quickly and a lot was assumed)
Thank you

Comment: Your second question is easy. Since $(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-2017)$ has $2017$ factors of degree-$1$ polynomials, it has a degree of $2017$. Then any nonzero polynomial $P(x)$ has $\deg P\geq 0$. Therefore the product $P(x)(x-1)\cdots(x-2017)$ has a degree of at least $2017$ if $P(x)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously $p(n)=n+1$ is such a polynomial. Now suppose there exists a polynomial $p(n)$ of degree $2016 \geq d>1$ such that,

$$p(n)=n+1$$

For $n=1,2,....,2016,2017$.

Then,

$$p(n)-n-1=0$$

Has at least $2017$ roots (1,2,3,...2016,2017) etc. But by the fundamental theorem of algebra, since $p(n)-n-1$ is of degree $d \leq 2016$,...(can you finish).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lagrange's interpolation formula to get the unique polynomial with the said properties as follows:

Set your data points $(1,p(1)),(2,p(2))\cdots $as $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\cdots $respectively, then your interpolating polynomial is given by
$$p(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{2017} a_n(x)y_n$$

where $a_n(x)=\prod_{j=1,j\neq n}^{2017}\frac{x-x_j}{x_n-x_j}$.
 For a general proof look at the proof of Lagrange's interpolation formula.